# Custom aggregation that acts on more than one columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Note that this question does **not** ask whether in pandas we can apply functions on more than one columns during aggregation. Here is an example:

The data frame:

```
A x y
foo 0 0
foo 1 1
foo 2 2
foo 3 3
bar 0 2
bar 2 3
bar 4 4
bar 6 5
```

I want to group this table by column `A` and compute the linear regression `y=k*x+b` on each group. So we want to achieve this:

```
A k b
foo 1.0 0.0
bar 0.5 2.0
```

I tried group by index `A`, and use `aggregate` method:

```py
grouped = table.groupby('A')
grouped.aggregate(f)

def f():
    pass
```

While I find out that this method will split the tabel into series and feed this series into the function `f`, so `f` cannot access two columns at the same time.

So, how can I do such "aggregation" function that acts on multiple columns in a split-apply-combine style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html):

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

out = (df.groupby('A', as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda g: pd.Series(linregress(g['x'], g['y'])[:2],
                                    index=['k', 'b']))
       )
```

*NB. the first two output parameters of `linregress` are your `k` and `b`.*

Output:

```
     A    k    b
0  bar  0.5  2.0
1  foo  1.0  0.0
```

Solution with custom function:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

def f(x):
    t = linregress(x['x'], x['y'])
    return pd.Series({'k': t.slope, 'b': t.intercept})

df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(f)
print (df)
     A    k    b
0  bar  0.5  2.0
1  foo  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Added another idea.

Comment: very helpful in demonstrating `groupby.apply` and providing examples, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If need processing multiple columns togther use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

```
def f(x):
    print (x)

grouped = table.groupby('A').apply(f)
```